# How to find polysemous words from given input query?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

If my input query is:

**"Dog is barking at tree"**

here word "bark" is polysemous word and we know that. But how to check it through a code in python language using wordnet as a lexical database?

Comment: You seem to be mixing [*polysemy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) and [*homonymy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonymy). Are you looking for any kind of ambiguity, or specifically one or the other?

Answer (score -1):

If a word has multiple synsets then you can say it is a polysemous word.